# Vertical space between two paragraph (only)

Tags: spacing, paragraphs

I would like to increase the vertical space between two specific paragraphs. These paragraphs are already in a deep section (`\subsubsection{}`) so I do not want to put each paragraph inside a `\paragraph{}` : it would complexity my paper and I do not want to create titles for theses paragraphs.

I have other paragraphs inside this section but I want to increase the vertical space only for the two paragraphs mentioned. Indeed the other paragraph breaks are less important.

I have two question :

1. Is it a good practice to separate the text like this? If no, why should I use?
2. How to create this big vertical space between these paragraphs?

Comment: Spacing provides emphasis, just like a change in font shape/weight/size. Use it sparingly. Perhaps try `\smallskip`, or `\medskip` or `\bigskip`.

Comment: as @Werner said or `<blank line>\vspace{5.247mm}` if you want to add an explict amount of extra space.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As the comments on your question said, you want one of `\smallskip`, `\medskip`, `bigskip`, or `\vspace{<amount>}`.

As an example (note that `\vspace` accepts absolute length in `pt`, `mm`, `cm`, or `in`, and *relative* length with `ex`—the height of an 'x' in the current font—and with the more common `em`, the width of an uppercase 'M').

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
\smallskip

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
\medskip

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
\bigskip

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
\vspace{3.5mm}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
\vspace{10mm}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.

\end{document}
```

produces

[image: Line spacing through different means]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)